# Binary search using recursion results in correct number but wrong index in Javascript

Tags: javascript, binary-search

I am a newbie to algorithm, I tried using recursion in binary search, I do get the result and it is correct, but the index of the result is wrong, I've tried over and over but just cannot the problem causing this. Here is my code:

```
function binarySearch(arr, num, pivot) {
  const center = Math.round(arr.length / 2);
  if (arr.length == 1 && arr[0] == num) {
    return `num is :${arr} pivot is : ${pivot}`;
  } else if (arr.length == 1 && arr[0] !== num) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (pivot == undefined) {
    pivot = center;
  }
  // console.log(`center is :${center}, pivot is ${pivot}`);
  if (arr[center] == num) {
    return `num is :${arr[center]} pivot is : ${[pivot - 1]}`;
  } else if (arr[center] < num) {
    return binarySearch(arr.slice(center, arr.length), num, pivot + 1);
  } else {
    return binarySearch(arr.slice(0, center), num, pivot - 1);
  }
}
```

thank you for the response in advance!

Comment: The problem is you are loosing information when making the recursive call if the number you're looking for is in the second half of the array. Try your algorithm using pen and paper for the array [1, 2] and num 2 and you'll realize. Fixing it should be a fun exercise for yourself :)

Comment: thank you mr burkay, I've found my problem after I set the start of my pivot as 0, it was quite an interesting exercise.

Comment: glad you figured it out:)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know that when writing a recursive function, there are two main states to consider: 1- the base case and 2- the recursive case. In the base case, it is the simplest condition where the recursive function stops its iterations. The recursive case is the situation where the function continues to call itself until the problem is broken down to the base case.

Now, considering we want to implement a binary search algorithm using this technique, where we track the index of the found element, we need to maintain the state of the broken-down array, the lower bound (low), and the upper bound (high) in the function. This will help us understand where the array is being broken down and allow us to determine the exact index of the item we are looking for.

I believe the issue with your code is that you are not preserving the break down state in your function. Therefore, you cannot determine your current position. Since the problem enters the recursive part with a new set, essentially a new array, it loses track of its original lower and upper bounds. To preserve these two essential states, you can write the function as follows, so that if the item is in the array, its index will be returned based on the original array and its position in the original array will be returned for the new set.

```
function binarySearchRecurse(list: number[], item: number, low: number = 0, high: number = list.length - 1): number | null {
    // base case
    if (low > high) return null;
    // recurse case 
    let mid = Math.ceil((low + high) / 2)
    if (list[mid] === item) return mid;
    if (list[mid] > item) {
        return binarySearchRecurse(list, item, low, mid - 1);
    } else if (list[mid] < item) {
        return binarySearchRecurse(list, item, mid + 1, high);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem in the OPs code was, what you changed, and how this fixed it

Comment: @Bergi Thank you, I hope I have provided a good explanation..